# ISSUE: Error (10818): Can't infer register for "y[0]" at FSM_LCD.vhd(42) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge

Tags: process, vhdl, clock, fsm

I'm trying to implement a finite state machine that has a delay(500ns) between each state transition with a 50Mhz clock, so 25 clock cycles delay.
Notice that: 
EA=current state
PE=next state
reset "resets" when 0

---

I was making a count from y=0 to y=M, but it gives the same error:
"Error (10818): Can't infer register for "y[0]" at FSM_LCD.vhd(42) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge"

Do anyone know how to fix this?
Here's a bit of the code (It has one more process using S0 until S14):

```
architecture automat of FSM_LCD is
    type states is (S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6_00, S6_01, S6_10, S6_11, S7_0, S7_1, S8, S9, S10, S11, S12, S13, S14);
    signal EA, PE: states;
    signal clock: std_logic;
    signal reset: std_logic;
    signal y : integer := 0;--y sera' acrescido ate' M de modo a criar um delay
    constant M : integer := 5;--diferenciar valor ao simular e ao executar por hardware
    signal n : integer := 0;

    begin
        clock <= Clk;
        reset <= Rst;
        EA <= S0;--apenas ao ativar o FSM pela primeira vez

        P1: process(clock, reset)
                begin
                    if reset = '0' then 
                        EA <= S3;--S0,S1 e S2 sao setup, ignorar-los ao resetar?
                    elsif clock'event and clock = '1' and y = 0 then 
                        EA <= PE;
--                  elsif y = M then
--                      y <= 0;--estados so' mudarao se n = 0
                    end if;
            end process;

        P2: process(clock)
            begin
                if clock = '1' then
                    y <= (y+1);
                elsif y = M then
                y <= 0;
                end if;
                n <=y;
            end process;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite P2 into a normal synchronous (clocked) process form.

Much better formatting, by the way; a lot easier to read than the previous question.

```
    P2: process(clock)
        begin
            if rising_edge(clock) then
               if y = m then
                  y <= 0;
               else 
                  y <= y + 1;
               end if;
            end if;
        end process;
```

would be synthesisable and, as far as I can tell, do what you want.

However I normally don't use a separate process for a delay in an SM:

I would combine both processes and suggest something like:

```
    signal delay : integer;

    P1: process(clock, reset)
        begin
           if reset = '0' then 
              -- reset actions here
           elsif rising_edge(clock) then 
              if delay = 0 then
                 EA <= PE;
                 delay <= M;
              else 
                 delay <= delay - 1;
              end if;
           end if;
        end process;
```

I would also roll the combinational process into this one too, but that's another story!

Comment: (when I press enter it adds the comment instead of jumping line)

Comment: I did what you told me, but now I get the following error: Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "EA.S0" at FSM_LCD.vhd(29)
picture: http://puu.sh/5kq38.png

Comment: That's because you have multiple drivers for "EA". The other one is just above the process and shouldn't be there.

Comment: http://puu.sh/5ktbW.png
Well, modelsim doesn't want to run it, it says "Case statement choices cover only 4 out of 81 cases.", which I found pointless, since "Operacao" has only 2 bits, far from 81 combinations as said...

Comment: Operacao has 2 bits, each of which takes 9 possible values (including "Z", "X" etc.  So 9**2 = 81 possible cases ... good job Modelsim! Add a "when others" clause to cover the others. I suggest `when others => report "Operacao problem!" severity failure`